# set HSSFCell with long text

Tags: java, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I am using `POI HSSFWorkbook` to generate excel sheet.
I need to add a large string to `HSSFCell`, I have tried using all possibilities as below to set the value but I couldn't see anything in the excel file which has been generated.

```
sb.append("A long text which has nearly 4000 characters");
cell.setCellValue(sb.toString());
```

Comment: The [POI class which contains all the spreadsheet format limits](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html#EXCEL97) suggests `.xls` should be fine with cells of up to `32767` characters long. Is it something as simple as the wrapping / column width?

Comment: Kindly provide a substantial chunk of code for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: as @Gagravarr said, it  allows 32767 characters. There was small mistake from my side with cellstyle alignment. Now it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @gagravarr said cell can store up to 32767 characters long.
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html#EXCEL97